# LARAVEL webpack

Tags: laravel, webpack

I am using LARAVEL 5.4.

I did versioning of css and js using webpack, which generated mix-manifest.json file in public folder.

While uploading on server , I moved out public folder content to project root folder.

Error - mix manifest does not exist.

Question - how to change manifest path so that it should search manifest.json in root folder.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to move your public folder? Better link your domains to /path/to/public/. Otherwise it poses a **security risk**

Comment: @manniL you mean to say the URL should be - www.domainname/public/route-name .?

Comment: No, I mean that http://www.youdomain.com/ should be "mapped" to /path/to/public. So no "public" in the url

Comment: thanks, for the idea, Can you tell how to achieve

Comment: Well, that depends on what you are using. If you have a server/VPS, adapt your apache config. When using a config panel, you can set the path the domain should point to in it.

Comment: Thanks, Again.  I have hosted my website on linux server C Panel.  the project directory is as it is as we download Laravel Project.    Index.php is in Public folder and public folder is in public_html.   Now where and in which file i should change.???   Or i should redirect www.domainname.com to www.domainname.com/public   .  but i don't want public. ?  Again i want the directory structure as the default structure the way laravel fresh project has..

Comment: You should (internally) set your domain to point to your `public_html/public` folder. Otherwise you reveal your internal folders (like resources, tests etc.) to the public audience. They can just go for domain.com/resources e.g.

Comment: Thanks. I dont want to reveal anything to audience. ?  But the same question how to   ---     set your domain to point to your public_html/public ---   in laravel project.?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel does not allow you to manage your httpd.conf file for apache to link your main domain name to your /home/USERNAME/public_html/public folder.  When you add an addon domain or a subdomain however, you *can* choose the folder the domain name has to be linked to.

There are also some tutorials out there that would allow you to change /public into /public_html for your laravel set, allowing you to stay within your cPanel boundaries, but I wouldn't recommend you doing so.

Personally I'd advise you to host your Laravel site or app on a DigitalOcean droplet or AWS instance in stead of on a cPanel based account, but I do realise that this might come at a higher cost for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but now i think this will help you get ride of that.

but my folder structure a bit different from yours. i had packed the framework in one folder name "framework" and i extracted the public folder to the main directory, in your Cpanel you will have to copy everything inside the laravel public folder and past it direct into the public_HTML. it should look like:

Public_HTML
 - framework (all the laravel file are in this folder)
 - css
 - js
 - images
 - .htaccess
 - favicon.ico
 - index.php
 - mix-manifest.json
 - robots.txt
 - web.config
Note: copy everything in the laravel public folder and past here

now you need to change the index.php file these 2 line

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/framework/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/framework/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now we continue to edit and change the Mix function from

file path: framework\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php

```
if (! function_exists('mix')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to a versioned Mix file.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $manifestDirectory
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    function mix($path, $manifestDirectory = '')
    {
        static $manifest;

        if (! starts_with($path, '/')) {
            $path = "/{$path}";
        }

        if ($manifestDirectory && ! starts_with($manifestDirectory, '/')) {
            $manifestDirectory = "/{$manifestDirectory}";
        }

        if (file_exists(public_path($manifestDirectory.'/hot'))) {
            return new HtmlString("//localhost:8080{$path}");
        }

        if (! $manifest) {
            if (! file_exists($manifestPath = public_path($manifestDirectory.'/mix-manifest.json'))) {
                throw new Exception('The Mix manifest does not exist.');
            }

            $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents($manifestPath), true);
        }

        if (! array_key_exists($path, $manifest)) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Unable to locate Mix file: {$path}. Please check your ".
                'webpack.mix.js output paths and try again.'
            );
        }

        return new HtmlString($manifestDirectory.$manifest[$path]);
    }
}
```

To

```
if (! function_exists('mix')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to a versioned Mix file.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $manifestDirectory
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    function mix($path, $manifestDirectory = '/../..')
    {
        static $manifests = [];

        if (! starts_with($path, '/')) {
            $path = "/{$path}";
        }

        if ($manifestDirectory && ! starts_with($manifestDirectory, '')) {
            $manifestDirectory = "{$manifestDirectory}";
        }

        $manifestKey = $manifestDirectory ? $manifestDirectory : '/';

//        if (file_exists(public_path($manifestDirectory.'/hot'))) {
//            return new HtmlString("//localhost:8080{$path}");
//        }

        if (in_array($manifestKey, $manifests)) {
            $manifest = $manifests[$manifestKey];
        } else {
            if (! file_exists($manifestPath = public_path($manifestDirectory.'/mix-manifest.json'))) {
                throw new Exception('The Mix manifest does not exist.');
            }

            $manifests[$manifestKey] = $manifest = json_decode(
                file_get_contents($manifestPath), true
            );
        }

        if (! array_key_exists($path, $manifest)) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Unable to locate Mix file: {$path}. Please check your ".
                'webpack.mix.js output paths and try again.'
            );
        }

        return new HtmlString($manifestDirectory.$manifest[$path]);
    }
}
```

Hope this help,

Comment: This is a workaround and will for sure break your laravel application on many aspects, so better stick to original laravel convention and don't mess with its directory structure. The only thing you need to set up is DOCUMENT_ROOT pointing to /public in webserver config or in cpanel in your case... AND last thing is, if you are about to change anything in /vendor/... then your are doing something completely wrong...